# SpecFlow - HTML output from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I'm trying to generate a nice HTML output for my specflow features from Visual Studio.  I have resharper installed and I can run my feature tests but I would like to get an html output of the final results.

I have tried several sites which say we can create an External Tools.  Here are my settings:

```
Title: SpecFlow Test Result

Command:C:\TFS\Test_Automation\a.1_Main\Test\AutoUpdateTests\AutoUpdateTests\packages\SpecFlow.1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe

Arguments: nunitexecutionreport AutoUpdateTests.csproj /xmlTestResult:bin\debug\TestResult.xml

Initial directory: $(ProjectDir)
```

so then I execute my tests and then select Tools -> SpecFlow Test Result

I see a cmd window open briefly but no TestResult.xml file appears.

Any ideas? I also have referenced nunit.framework in my project not sure that matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [blog post](http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/specflowexe-and-mstest.html) that describes how this is accomplished, yes it's about MsTest but the general idea is the same

Also - in the last 2 minutes of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVwBz-ZTliw) Rob Conery hooks Visual Studio up with the SpecFlow test runner, if you rather watch than read.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't fussy about the format, then there is another way to achieve this,

1. Download a free copy of [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/index.html) (Other CI servers exist)
2. Add a visual Studio Build step to build your project
3. Add an nUnit Build step to run your tests
4. Look in the build log

> [x.Tests.dll]
> x.Tests.ConfirmThatSchedulesStartAndStopFeature.ProvideAFakeDateTime_Now
>
> Given a schedule called Calc
>
> -> done: ScheduleModelTest.GivenAScheduleCalled("Calc") (0.0s)
>
> And my schedule thinks its Monday 8:00
>
> -> done: ScheduleModelTest.GivenMyScheduleThinksIts("Monday", "8:00") (0.0s)
>
> Then my schedule should tell me its Monday 8:00
>
> -> done: ScheduleModelTest.ThenMyScheduleShouldTellMeIts("Monday", "8:00") (0.0s)